# Two similar codes providing different answers

Tags: python, machine-learning, scikit-learn, svm, tfidfvectorizer

I have written two programs to explore text messages and create models to predict if a message is a spam message or not.

In both SVC models: I used a Tfidf Vectorizer, set `max_df=5`, and added a new column with the length of the document.

This is the first piece of code and this returns the ROC AUC score as 0.85:

```
def spam_or_not():
    v = TfidfVectorizer(max_df=5).fit(X_train)
    l_train = [len(x) for x in X_train]
    l_test = [len(x) for x in X_test]
    x_train_text = v.transform(X_train) 
    x_train = add_feature(x_train_text,l_train) #add_features returns sparse feature matrix with added feature.
    x_test_text = v.transform(X_test)
    x_test = add_feature(x_test_text , l_test)
    clf = SVC(C=10000)
    clf.fit(x_train,y_train)
    y_predict = clf.predict(x_test)
    return roc_auc_score(y_test,y_predict)
```

This is the second code and this gives a score of 0.95.

```
def spam_or_not():
    length_X_train = list(map(len,X_train))
    length_X_test = list(map(len,X_test))
    vect = TfidfVectorizer(min_df=5).fit(X_train)
    X_train_vectorized = vect.transform(X_train)
    X_test_vectorized = vect.transform(X_test)
    x_test_text = vect.transform(X_test)
    x_train = add_feature(X_train_vectorized,length_X_train)
    x_test = add_feature(X_test_vectorized , length_X_test)
    clf = SVC(C=10000)
    clf.fit(x_train,y_train)
    y_predict = clf.predict(x_test)
    score = roc_auc_score(y_test,y_predict)
    return roc_auc_score(y_test, y_predict)
```

These look the same to me but give really different results. If  someone can show me the difference I'd appreciate it.

Answer (score 2):

I can spot at least one difference:

```
v = TfidfVectorizer(max_df=5).fit(X_train)
```

versus

```
vect = TfidfVectorizer(min_df=5).fit(X_train)
```

- The first one sets the **maximum** document frequency to 5, which means ignoring the frequent terms.
- The second sets the **minimum** to 5, which means ignoring the rare terms.

That's going to cause a massive difference in the TFIDF weights, hence very different results.